# How can I remove corners from a Button?

Tags: vb.net, button, drawing

I'm trying to remove corners that are not included in the button border.

I draw my button border with this method:

```
Private Sub BTN_Connexion_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles BTN_Connexion.Paint
    Me.DrawRectangle(e.Graphics, New Pen(Color.White), 0, 0, BTN_Connexion.Width - 1, BTN_Connexion.Height - 1, 10) 
End Sub

Public Sub DrawRectangle(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal pen As Pen, ByVal x As Int32, ByVal y As Int32, ByVal width As Int32, ByVal height As Int32, ByVal radius As Int32)
    'Create a rectangle
    Dim area As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, width, height)
    Dim path As Drawing2D.GraphicsPath = New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath

    'Add the corners
    path.AddArc(area.Left, area.Top, radius * 2, radius * 2, 180, 90) 'Upper-Left
    path.AddArc(area.Right - (radius * 2), area.Top, radius * 2, radius * 2, 270, 90) 'Upper-Right
    path.AddArc(area.Right - (radius * 2), area.Bottom - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2, 0, 90) 'Lower-Right
    path.AddArc(area.Left, area.Bottom - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2, 90, 90) 'Lower-Left
    path.CloseAllFigures()

    'Draw the rounded rectangle
    g.DrawPath(pen, path)
End Sub
```

Corners can take the main form color. Like this they would not appear on the button. But I don't know if it's good practice and more I didn't know how to do this.

So could you tell me how can I remove these corners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my problem, here is the solution:

In the form that you want to implement your rounded button do:

```
Private Sub BTN_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles BTN_Connect.Paint, BTN_Disconnect.Paint
    DirectCast(sender, Button).Region = New Region(SpecificDesign.DrawRoundRectangle(0, 0, BTN_Connect.Width - 1, BTN_Connect.Height - 1, 10))
End Sub
```

The class `SpecificDesign` contains:

```
Public Class SpecificDesign
   ''' <summary>
   ''' Create the path of a rounded rectangle.
   ''' </summary>
   ''' <param name="left">Ordinate of the left top corner</param>
   ''' <param name="Top">Abscissa of the left top corner</param>
   ''' <param name="width">Width of the rounded rectangle (Left and right lines)</param>
   ''' <param name="height">Height of the rounded rectangle(Top and bottom lines)</param>
   ''' <param name="radius">Radius of the rounded corner </param>
   ''' <returns></returns>
   Public Shared Function DrawRoundRectangle(ByVal left As Int32, ByVal Top As Int32, ByVal width As Int32, ByVal height As Int32, ByVal radius As Int32) As Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
          Dim path As Drawing2D.GraphicsPath = New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath

          path.AddArc(left, Top, radius * 2, radius * 2, 180, 90) 'Upper-Left
          path.AddArc(left + width - (radius * 2), Top, radius * 2, radius * 2, 270, 90) 'Upper-Right
          path.AddArc(left + width - (radius * 2), Top + height - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2, 0, 90) 'Lower-Right
          path.AddArc(left, Top + height - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2, 90, 90) 'Lower-Left
          path.CloseAllFigures()

          Return path
   End Function
End Class
```